# Which Subversion web interfaces have a blame feature?

Tags: svn, version-control, blame

I'm looking for a **subversion web client** ala [SVN::Web](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SVN-Web/) but with a very specific feature I've always thought would be quite useful.

What I want is the ability to find **which revision was responsible for a certain line** (or lines) in a text file.  A way to do this via the web would be fantastic.

Anybody know of such a tool?

Comment: SVN::Web has blame/annotate view.

Comment: Try the blame view in VisualSVN Server's web ui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602358/761095 and https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/blame/head/subversion/trunk/subversion/tests/README?line=34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [Warehouse](http://www.warehouseapp.com/), and are quite happy with it.  It's written in Ruby on Rails, so if you're well versed in that, you're far ahead of the game.  They also just went [open source](http://github.com/entp/warehouse/tree/master).

Comment: That is a beautiful application.

Comment: Sure is!  It has some bugs, but now that it's open source, those should quickly disappear :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to have the annotate feature though :-?

Comment: Actually, it does have Blame support. See http://activereload.net/2008/1/8/warehouse-v1-1-5-svn-blame-simpler-dns-setup for a screenshot.

Comment: Is this software available nowadays? The first link leads to nowhere, github link gives 404 not found error.

Answer (score 5):

I use [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/), you can use *svn blame* from there, and you see who and when added or modified each line of code in a file...

**Edit:** Here are a pair of screenshots, so you can get an idea:

[image: 1], [image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

Trac can do this for you. When you view a file, you have an annotate option at the top of the page, which will use ajax to load a bar down the left of the file source, giving the revision numbers for each line (or block, if a block was edited in one commit)

It'd be nice to see something that had a revision history for each line though.

Answer (score 1):

The SVN::Web interface gives you access to the svn blame annotation(s) on files.

When you're viewing a specific file, you should see "**Blame/Annotate**" as one of the links in the upper left. When you click on it, you have a much more-marked-up rendition of the file, with blocks in alternating colors. These delinate where contiguous blocks belonging to a given rev start and end. To the left are the user-names of the users whose commits were responsible for a given block, and to the left of that a linked number indicating the revision that the particular block stems from. Clicking on the link will take you to the revision-view page, that lists all the files changed in that revision, along with color-coded diffs of the files/changes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

[Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) also supports the 'blame' feature.

Comment: The question was specifically about a Web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that SVN had the 'blame' function that could do something similar to that. I am taking a stab in the dark though.  Hold on while I take a quick look through the interwebs.

You bet.  Check [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html) out.  (I use subclipse btw)

This implies that most web SVN interfaces will have this feature because it is not anything really special.

Comment: doesnt answer the question. They want a web client that can use svn blame, not the technicalities of it.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN Server's web UI has a blame view. Check the demo at https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/blame/r1873567/subversion/trunk/subversion/tests/README?line=34

In the blame view, each line in the file includes the author's name, date, log message, and revision number. The view also has the **Blame previous revision** command that helps navigate to earlier revisions and examine the details of changes. See screenshots below.

*Blame view overview*
[image]

*Log message*
[image]

*Blame previous revision*
[image]